# Cleaning Text in a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text, data-cleaning

I am not a programmer and a newbie in coding.. I am trying to do some text cleaning on **srt** file by concatenating, Hindi and English subtitles

the text I am getting has *;* ; \n tags within it, though not all converted lines have this. How can I clean the text.

[image]

following is my code:

```
    import pysrt
    import pandas as pd
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
    subs = pysrt.open("../input/movie-subtitles/Free-Guy_2021_English-ELSUBTITLE.COM-ST_62579580.srt")
    
    data = {"time": [], "eng_lines": []} 
    for sub in subs:
        lines = sub.text
        time = sub.duration
        data["time"].append(time.to_time())
        data["eng_lines"].append(lines)
        
    df_eng = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_eng
    
    subs = pysrt.open("../input/movie-subtitles/Free-Guy_2021_Hindi-ELSUBTITLE.COM-ST_62579580.srt")
    
    data = {"time": [], "hin_lines": []} 
    for sub in subs:
        lines = sub.text
        time = sub.duration
        data["time"].append(time.to_time())
        data["hin_lines"].append(lines)
        
    df_hin = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    df= pd.concat([df_hin,df_eng],axis=1)
```

Comment: what did you try? How about standard `text.replace("\n", "").replace("<i>", "")` and `df.apply(...)` to run function with `replace`. But `pandas` should also have own `replace` and it may uses `regex`.

Comment: better put example data as text so we could simply copy it and use in solution.